# How do I concatenate string and an integer?

Tags: python, excel, string, integer, xlsxwriter

```
act = input("Enter name of the activity")
cellone = int(input("Enter the order number of activity"))
cell1 = "A" + cellone
worksheet.write(cell1, act)
```

I'm trying to concatenate `A` and `cellone` but I'm getting some error saying that I can't concatenate string and an integer, is there a way to do this?

Comment: You don't actually need to concatenate the string and integer. The XlsxWriter `write()` function take integer values as well as strings so you could just do this: `worksheet.write(cellone -1, 0, act)`. See the XlsxWriter docs: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `int` to a `string` representation using this:

```py
cell1="A"+str(cellone)
```

Alternatively, [`f-string` formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) will also work:

```py
cell1=f"A{cellone}"
```

Comment: I agree with this answer. f-string is a preferred way for Python as of now. Not only it's cleaner, it's faster as well.

Comment: @IamThuYa indeed it's faster and easy, but still a "hack". In a professional environment where thousands of lines are reviewed and maintained, it's very important to maintain the logic behind the writing. In the first case the developer shows that he's casting a string in order to concat with 'A', while in the second it's like reformatting the variable.

Comment: @CommissarVasiliKarlovic I agree with maintaining the logic but this is not a "hack". For python at least, we care about pythonic ways. Using f-string provide so much more control over plain casting. If the variable is a float, with f-string I can control how many decimal I want to use, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`str(cellone)` returns the value of `cellone` as a string.

```
call1="a"+str(cellone)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the int in line 2 as follows:

`cellone=input("Enter the order number of activity")`

It takes the input as a string data type anyway

Answer (score 1):

Just dont convert the string to int. correct that to

```py
cellone=input("Enter the order number of activity")
```